# "Error: write after end": ReactJS with web3js and MetaMask on Chrome

Tags: metamask, react

I have a ReactJS v18.2 project and use web3.js v1.8 for the blockchain connection. I have three environments: **local**, **test**, **main**.

**test** and **main** are both on the same server, but run on different domains: `test: test.hello.com`, `main: hello.com`. **local** is just a local instance for developing.

I encounter the error below only on **test** if I connected myself via **MetaMask** to one of the environments (**local**, **test**, **main**).

```
Error in event handler: Error: write after end
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/contentscript.js:17:32188
  at b.write (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/contentscript.js:17:32251)
  at t.exports.g (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/contentscript.js:17:22060)
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/contentscript.js:8:23750
  at o.emit (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/contentscript.js:8:23760)
  at _ (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/contentscript.js:17:16863)
  at w (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/contentscript.js:17:16678)
  at v.push (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/contentscript.js:17:17489)
  at t.exports._onMessage (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/contentscript.js:8:46038)
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/contentscript.js:8:45885
```

I thought that MetaMask only connects the wallet to the specific (sub-)domain (e.g. `test.hello.com`), but if i connect myself to my **main** instance, the **test** environment also shows a connection even though I did not connect my wallet to it in the same browser session.

How can I resolve the error and why does it happen in the first place?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I don't think it's domain related. https://community.metamask.io/t/provider-not-getting-connected/27309/2